# Search for placeholders fail when they are consecutive

Tags: regex

I have to search a placeholder character in a string. The rules are simple:

1. The placeholder has to be surrounded by whitespaces.
2. Except at the beginning of the text.
3. Except at the at the end of the text.
4. Except for a some special characters direct after the placeholder.

I've created a regex expression that would fit this rules.

```
(?:^|\s)(?<Platzhalter>\$)(?:$|\s|\,|\.)
```

It's working fine except when there are two or more consecutive placeholders like this:

```
$ $
$.$
```

I do not understand why the expression fails in this cases.

How can I change the expression that it would capture those cases too?

Greetings,
Stefan

Comment: It is a very common issue. Use lookarounds: `(?<=^|\s)(?<Platzhalter>\$)(?=$|[\s,.])`

Comment: You could use `(?<!\S)(?<Platzhalter>\$)(?=$|[\s,.])`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've changed it to `(?<=^|[\s.,])(?<Platzhalter>\$)(?=$|[\s,.])`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! I have changed the expression. Now it looks like this:

```
(?<=^|[\s.,])(?<Platzhalter>\$)(?=$|[\s,.])
```